# Instance of PCP problem : is it solvable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, computer-science

Are the following instances of post correspondence problem solvable? Find, if possible, various non-periodic solutions or prove the insolubility.

1. $\alpha = (11, 01, 001)$, $\beta = (011, 0, 110)$
2. $\alpha = (101, 100, 0, 00111)$, $\beta = (1, 0, 010, 010111)$

For the first one I tried  various sequences but I didnt find a common sequence so I suppose that this one is not solvable. Is that correct?

To prove that, we suppose that the problem is solvable.

There exists a $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and a sequence of indices $i_1, \ldots , i_k\in \{1, 2, 3\}$ with $\alpha_{i_1}\dots \alpha_{i_k}=\beta_{i_1}\dots \beta_{i_k}$.

How can we continue to get a contradiction? Or is the problem solvable?

At the second one, the number of "0" in $\alpha$ is not the same as the number of "0" in $\beta$. Would that imply that this problem is also not solvable?

Answer (score 1):

1. What possible values can $i_k$ and $i_{k-1}$ have?
2. There are several common sequences with 4 symbols. Can you find all three?

Comment: 1. $i_k$ must be $1$ so that the two wprds end with the same letter, correct? $i_{k-1}$ must be the index of a string that ends with $0$ in $\alpha$ to be identical with $\beta$. That is not possible and so there is no solution. Is that correct? $$$$ 2. Do you mean that the solution should contain 4 indices? For example, one solution is (1,3), or not? Or can we not use just two strings of the given set?

Comment: 1. That is correct.

2. I mean that the common string contains 4 symbols. You already found one such string, $1010$. That is already enough to solve the problem.

Comment: So a solution doesn't have to contain all the strings of the sets, correct?

Comment: That's right. Some strings may also be used several times.